# add a new line to text file in php using file_put_contents

Tags: php, html

I need to add a new line to a text file, but the following code skips one line. please help me

```
file_put_contents("singles.txt","\n".$userData, FILE_APPEND);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this;

```
file_put_contents("singles.txt", $userData . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
```

`\n` adds new line, you need to remove that

Comment: OP wants to add a new line, not to remove that.

Comment: OP used new line at the start of text, I removed from start, put it to the end

Comment: could you please show an example text output that you want to achieve?

Comment: @user3513160, None seems to work statement is not going to help us , please post the **expected output** on your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   file_put_contents("singles.txt",$userData."\n", FILE_APPEND);
```

Comment: more detail please...show where you are using file_put_contents()

Comment: actually i used php_eol and it works now, I just closed the file and reopened it. Quick question: What would be the right method to check if the new information is in the file already

Comment: Many ways try this and google 
if( strpos(file_get_contents("singles.txt"),"stringtocheck") !== -1)

Comment: thank you, i will try it tomorrow. In this part of the world is really late

Answer (score 0):

Use `PHP_EOL` instead.

```
$userData = $userData.PHP_EOL;
file_put_contents("singles.txt",$userData, FILE_APPEND);
```

Comment: skips even more lines